# What is main() here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've seen code such as:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What does `main()` mean there? Is it a function of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

main() is a function. However, you need to define it. If you have ever used another programming language, such as Java, C, or C++, you'd have heard of a main method. You define your own main method, then tell Python to use it immediately. It is typically just for good practice, so for example

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

def main():
    print("Hello, World")
```

Is the same as

```
print("Hello, World")
```

Later on in your Python career, you will learn the benefits of this script.

Comment: whats the point of main methods/functions

Comment: A method is a group of code that runs every time you run the function. Try following a basic tutorial for this information

Answer (score 0):

Its your main function
You should add

```
def main():
    blabla...
```

Answer (score 0):

example1.py

```
print ("Always executed example1")

def main(param):
    print(param)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("Executed example1 when invoked directly ")
    main('main invoked directly')

else:
    print ("Executed example1 when imported")
    main('main invoked when imported')
```

example2.py

```
import example1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("Executed example2")
    example1.main('main invoked from example2 __name__')
```

Output when example1.py runs:

```
Always executed example1
Executed example1 when invoked directly 
main invoked directly
```

Output when example2.py runs:

```
Always executed example1
Executed example1 when imported
main invoked when imported
Executed example2
main invoked from example2 __name__
```

In simple words:
`main()` is jus a function defined and if it's under under `if __name__ == "__main__":`, will only get called upon when your Python file is executed as python example1.py

However, if you wish to import your Python file example1.py as a module to work with another Python file, say example2.py, the code under `if __name__ == "__main__":` will not run or take any effect.

Comment: what would you include in your main function?